# xml have different value when i add it to a variable

Tags: php

I have a webservice that returns a xml. If i make an echo, shows something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><ConsultaXMLout xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Respuestas><DatosIdiomas><DatosEnvios><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ4AT70700000370108173A" Evento="1" web_id="Sin web_id"><Estado>Pre registro</Estado><Fecha>09/10/2015</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ4AT70700000370108173A" Evento="2"><Estado>En tránsito.</Estado><Fecha>13/10/2015</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ4AT70700000370108173A" Evento="3"><Estado>Admitido</Estado><Fecha>13/10/2015</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ4AT70700000370108173A" Evento="4"><Estado>En tránsito.</Estado><Fecha>13/10/2015</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ4AT70700000370108173A" Evento="5"><Estado>En proceso de entrega</Estado><Fecha>14/10/2015</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ4AT70700000370108173A" Evento="6"><Estado>En proceso de entrega</Estado><Fecha>14/10/2015</Fecha></Datos><Datos Idioma="1" Codigo="PQ4AT70700000370108173A" Evento="7"><Estado>Entregado.</Estado><Fecha>14/10/2015</Fecha></Datos></DatosEnvios></DatosIdiomas></Respuestas></ConsultaXMLout>
```

If a copy manually this and I add it to a variable, the echo return this:

```
Pre registro09/10/2015En tránsito.13/10/2015Admitido13/10/2015En tránsito.13/10/2015En proceso de entrega14/10/2015En proceso de entrega14/10/2015
```

But if i add the xml directly to a variable, keeps the original shape. I need the second one. Why if technically are the same, change the way that they are showed. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the page source code? You might want to look into [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) as well.

Comment: The final problem was that simplexml was giving me an error for the 1st xml but not with the second. As I said in the other comment the problem was that i wasn't seeing the entire xml with the echo. Thanks.

Comment: Just fyi, there exists a [<pre> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) that will do what you want without having to use htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 0):

When you do an echo, your browser 'll not show tags the same way it dont show `<div>`/`<p>` etc ...

Try a "var_dump";

Comment: I tried var_dump, var_export, a variable with var_dump (thexml,true) but nothing works. Only if a copy manually the xml.

Comment: I found a solution, as you said echo wasn't showing the entire xml. Using htmlspecialchars i can see the hide part and with htmlspecialchars_decode i can make what i needed to do in the xml. Thanks.